# whats the best practice to implement social share buttons on a website?

Tags: facebook, twitter, social-networking

Whats the way to implement social share buttons on a HTML only website like Facebook, twitter and linkedin etc are there any good plugins out there that are customizable ?

or is wise to implement each social share button individually ?

at the moment I'm using addthis plugin and is not working very well and not finding much support for it on their forums.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes use the following site to generate my share codes:

http://sharethis.com/publishers/get-sharing-tools#

If you just want a specific page to share or want dev tools for Facebook check this out:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/